# What is the equivalent of an HTML audio blob in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I'm building a Windows Universal App, and I'm looking for the equivalent of this code in C#

```
var media = new Blob([bytes], { type: "audio/mpeg" });
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(media, { oneTimeOnly: true });
```

Basically, I have streams that I download, and want to play in the background; however, they need to be "saved" as an audio file locally, and I'm not sure how to do that in C#.

Comment: Is your whole application in C#? If so then you would have some type of `Stream` object which you could save to a `StorageFile`

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT - Yes, it's a C# app, but all methods that I've tried to convert my download stream to a local file, and then read it into the background audio manager don't seem to work. Audio just doesn't play. Strangely enough, I can get it to work via JavaScript and the above code I posted.

Comment: Can you post the C# code you've already tried, along with any error messages etc?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT - This is embarrassing, I just found the source of my problems. Looks like I was saving the file fine, but here's the offending line that caused me so much headache. `mediaPlayer.Volume = 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Object type “Blob” and function “createObjectURL” are both new HTML5 features. It is supported by the host (browser) and different browsers may have the different implementations, so it is very difficult to do the same thing in C#.

To save an audio file locally, you can use the [StorageFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.storage.storagefile.aspx) class in Windows Runtime.